# How to properly plot a density heat map using lat, lon and values as magnitude?

Tags: dictionary, plotly, heatmap

As info if useful, I am using spyder, my data set contains 4,173,841 data points and 69 columns, the file size is 3.05 Gb (after images there is still part of the explanation of my problem).

This is the code I am using:

```
data=pd.read_csv('/Users/Me/Documents/Python/JAN-2021-ee.csv')

import plotly.express as px

map = px.density_mapbox(data, lat='latitude',lon='longitude',z='Total emissions',radius=10,mapbox_style="stamen-terrain")

from plotly.offline import plot
plot(map)
```

This is what I get:
[image]

My aim to get something like this (built in tableau):

[image]

I have had a hard time trying to figure why I cannot get the same results or similar, any ideas I will really appreciate it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried having only one day as sample and ran the following code which is basically the same and I got a nice map plotted.

import pandas as pd

```
data=pd.read_csv('/Users/Documents/Python/jan-2021-ee.csv')
data['dtg']=pd.to_datetime(data['dtg'])
#data.info()

df=data[data['dtg']<'2021-1-3']
df

import plotly.express as px
map = px.density_mapbox(data_frame=df,lat='latitude',lon='longitude',z='Total emissions',mapbox_style='carto-positron',radius=5,zoom=5)
#data.columns

from plotly.offline import plot
plot(map)
```

And this was the result:
[image]

In few words, it is sad that plotly does not work for a good couple of thousand of sample points.